# How to write orderBy query in parse.com

Tags: java, android, database, parse-platform, nosql

I am building an Android messaging app using parse.com as backend. I want to find out top 10 users who have sent most number of messages.

parse.com doesn't support `orderBy` clause.

```
Database schema:

User(objectId[PK], username)
Message(objectId[PK], sender[ForeignKey], Receiver[ForeignKey]
```

could somebody please help me how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can order with `ParseQuery addAscendingOrder(keyToSortBy);`

So, if you have a field with number of sent messages (numberofmessages), the query would look like:

```
query.addAscendingOrder("numberofmessages");
```

http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#addAscendingOrder(java.lang.String)

Comment: no I do not have number of messages sent by a user in database.

Comment: So, what did you want to use orderBy for? If you need this functionality, it is not a good design to have a User and Message, and use just queries to solve the problem. This is a SQL-ish approach. You need to design the NoSQL way. Check my answer here to get a heads up on the principals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800038/nested-include-parse-com/22805652#22805652