# Nested Include Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a `UserToMessage` table which has a pointer to user called `thisUser` and a pointer to message called `msg`

The `message table` has a pointer to user called `creator`. When I query `UserToMessage` I `[includeKey:@"message"]`

I also want to `[includeKey:@"creator"]` somehow...

Comment: @ApperleyA don't "what?........" me..................

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserToMessage"];
[query includeKey:@"msg"];
[query includeKey:@"msg.creator"];

// Add constraints on query
...
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if(error) return;
    // Do action
    ...
}];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[includeKey:@"message.creator"]
```

You can even do this one level deeper: `message.creator.mother` - but not more than that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of asking yourself how you can include info from multiple tables in a JOIN-like query, you should ask yourself if you've designed the database model your app needs.

What you've written about your model sounds very SQL-ish. That's ok, though, as most people coming to parse.com and other NoSQL-backed services come from the SQL world. However, simply transfering a SQL database design into Parse does not usually provide an optimal solution.

Instead, focus on the queries first and determine what data they need to return. If you find you need data from 3 different classes returned in a query, that is a fault of the model. Developing an app for portable devices, you need to focus on query performance and calculation overhead.

You should design your database model in such a way that most (if not all) of your data will be accessible in as few queries as possible. Preferably one.

Typical solutions to this problem revolves around denormalisation and eventual consistency. 
For example, in a Twitter-like app, if you want to retrieve the posts made by the people you follow, it is not scaleable to get this by first querying for a person's "followings" and then query the tweet table for all tweets made by those people. It could work for a few followings and posts, but it would be unfeasible if you followed 100.000 people.

In a NoSQL scenario, when someone published a tweet, this post would be stored in the tweet table, and you would store a pointer to that tweet in an array in my feed object *and in the feed objects of each and every person following the author of the tweet!*

I know this seems odd (crazy, even) from a SQL database viewpoint, but not so for NoSQL systems. If I later deleted a tweet, the tweet would need to be removed from possibly 359.000 feed objects (if I was Barack Obama). This would not be immediate - hence "eventual consistency".

I recommend you sit down with pen and paper and rethink your database model based on the data you need to retrieve.

Comment: I'm one of those people with an SQL background and you're right, that example at the bottom does seem crazy. I'm not trying to disprove you here, I'd just like to learn more, but is that really true? If we look at today's scale, Obama as over 40 million followers - is it actually faster to create 40 million new records for each Tweet Obama would create than have individuals do that extra query? Again, not trying to disprove you - I'd love an elaboration to learn more about this :) thank you sir!

Comment: Well, "faster" is not really the question. You compare the time to create 40M records with querying 40M records (if all followers get the tweet). But what you should have in mind when you design the database is how to minimize the work for each USER; meaning mobile clients. If the creation of 40M records (extreme example, but still) is time consuming, that won't matter to the client as this all happens on the server. But each extra (un)necessary query will slow the client down, and the user experience will suffer.

Comment: To elaborate: when working with massive scales like Twitter almost any solution might seem crazy, as the volumes themselves are crazy. Imaging the more traditional approach: When I open my Twitter app to check my stream, the system would have to query all my hundreds of followings to get their latest posts. Not post, but posts. Then they would all have to be sorted chronologically before being presented in the stream. That is a large operation. But it gets even worse: the app doesn't just show the tweet itself, but also the screen name and picture of the tweeter. Would be a lot of queries...

Comment: So how much information would you "inline" so to speak? If we're appending the Tweet to an array for each follower when Obama Tweets, what do we do about Obama's details (like the name and thumbnail that you mentioned)? It's a similar deal, will that be "inlined" to? Where does it end..? Are we just adding IDs to these arrays so the user still has to query the data but with a simple key comparison instead of a range search? Sorry.. maybe we should hold this conversation elsewhere :P

Answer (score 0):

Ok this question is really confusing. If I understood correctly, You want to query the `UserToMessage` table and include two conditions? If so you could do it like this:

```
[query whereKey:@"msg" equalTo:MSG_POINTER];
[query whereKey:@"thisUser" equalTo:PF_USER_POINTER];
```

If this is not the case please update your question to reflect what exactly you need.