# Nested Parse Query to 3rd level

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I want to know about the query in which i can get the data from my table on the basis of 3rd level table result. Here is the details.

1. Table1 -> Pointer Column (Table2).
2. Table2-> Pointer Column (Table3).
3. Table3-> Pointer Column (Table4.)

I want to execute query on Table1 and want to get the result on the basis of TABLE 4 -> TABLE 3 -> TABLE 2 -> TABLE 1. What i mean is i want to find "A" in TABLE 4 and on the basis of result i want all the things of "A"  in TABLE 3 and then all the TABLE 3 found thing in TABLE 2 and then on that result all the things in TABLE 1. So how it can be possible :).

I know i can do that by calling separate queries. But i want short way if any possible.

Thanks in advance who ever solve my this problem.

Comment: You say that they're pointers, but then you say that you want all the things which is basically not possible because a pointer means 1 to 1 relation. To be more precise: if it is 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4, that's easy but if it is a tree (with relation instead of pointers) with more than one branch per node, it is more difficult

Comment: Btw, on which OS do you want that? Android or iOS

Comment: preference is iOS but i don't think there will be any change in action in both platform.

Comment: and as far as i understand pointer is a reference of object 1 to 1 but if we execute this.

1. Table1-> Pointer Column (Table 2).

  PFQuery *table2Query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Table2"];
    [statusQuery whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Online"];

 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Table1"];
    [query whereKey:@"table2" matchesQuery:table2Query];

it bring all the data of online users. By this query we can see that it is getting all the object IDs of Online and searching on table1 and getting result.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [BoltsFramework](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS#chaining-tasks-together). it was designed by `Parse`.

> Bolts include:
>
> "Tasks", which make organization of complex asynchronous code more
>   manageable. A task is kind of like a JavaScript Promise, but available
>   for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I figured out your data schema:

What you miss is the very useful `include` method: so [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-relational-queries) is the documentation for iOS and [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-relational-queries) for Android.

In pseudo code it'd look like this:

```
Create a query (let's say 'coolQuery') for table 1
Add to this query ('coolQuery') an include with table 2
Add to this query ('coolQuery') an include with table 2.table 3
Add to this query ('coolQuery') an include with table 2.table 3.table 4
```

Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515784/parse-include-nested-pointers-in-query) which is really good formulated. [Kind of the same idea for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22800348/2545832)
If you're interested here is the [blog post of Parse](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/queries-for-relational-data/) about this topic

Answer (score 0):

I have done some experiment by which i have sorted that we can only query upto second level if we go for 3rd level then we will get exception. Here is what i was doing.

```
PFQuery *Table4Query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Table4"];
[vehicleTypeQuery whereKey:@"name" equalTo:@"A"];    

PFQuery *Table3Query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Table3"];
[vehicleQuery whereKey:@"Table4PointerColumn" matchesQuery:Table4Query];

PFQuery *Table2Query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Table2"];
[Table2 whereKey:@"Table3PointerColumn" matchesQuery:Table3Query];


PFQuery *Table1Query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Table1"];

[query whereKey:@"Table2PointerColumn" matchesQuery:Table2Query];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) 
{

}
```

and i got the error

> "query has too many nested queries"

Then i tried this.

```
PFQuery *Table3Query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Table3"];
[vehicleQuery whereKey:@"Table4PointerColumn" equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Table4" objectId:@"kVQvan1E23"]];

PFQuery *Table2Query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Table2"];
[Table2 whereKey:@"Table3PointerColumn" matchesQuery:Table3Query];


PFQuery *Table1Query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Table1"];

[query whereKey:@"Table2PointerColumn" matchesQuery:Table2Query];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) 
{

}
```

and this is working perfect for me now i just need to query for Table4 separate to get the data.